# Count the moves of hanoi tower

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, count, global-variables

I am trying to count the moves of hanoi tower

```
In [4]: %paste      
count = 0
def hanoi(n, a, b, c):
    global count 
    if n == 1:
        count += 1
    else:
        hanoi(n - 1, a, c, b)
        hanoi(1, a, b, c)
        hanoi(n - 1, b, a, c)


hanoi(10, "A", "B", "C")
## -- End pasted text --

In [5]: print(count)
1023
```

The above solution employed the `global` keyword,
How could get it done if not introducing global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of refactoring to make the function recursive with a common `count` variable:

```
def hanoi(n, a, b, c):
    count = 0
    if n == 1:
        count += 1
    else:
        count += hanoi(n - 1, a, c, b)
        count += hanoi(1, a, b, c)
        count += hanoi(n - 1, b, a, c)
    return count
```

**Output**

```
>>> hanoi(10, "A", "B", "C")
1023
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even without any `count` variable:

```
def hanoi(n, a, b, c):
    if n != 1:
        return hanoi(n - 1, a, c, b) + hanoi(1, a, b, c) + hanoi(n - 1, b, a, c)
    return 1

print (hanoi(10, "A", "B", "C"))
```

**Output**

```
1023
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use complex codes for that. After all, that is math based, so just use this simple one line solution, that works every time in every code.
Place it in the end of hanoi code using tab ofc... but before 
hanoi(10, "A", "B", "C")
and remove all that "count" staff that was never even needed.

```
print(2**n-1)
```

Lets say, your hanoi code ends like this, with this math code:

```
def hanoi(n,f,h,t,):
    if n==0:
        pass
    else:
        hanoi(n-1,f,t,h)
        move(f,t)
        hanoi(n-1,h,f,t)
    print(2**n-1)
```

hanoi(4,"A","B","C")

And you do not have to make an other code to count that. Just chance the number at the and of code. Less is better and faster...
If you make all codes long and spread, it will slow down the results. PC:s are made to do math, so why should we not use that!?

The other thing is that, hanoi code itself is easier to make than these count codes. Lets compare with this randint code...
Hanoi code needs just one print/format on it like this:

```
print("Move object from {} to {}!" .format(f,t))
```

You can also get rid of int and str in code. Any option, you can cut out of code, makes its faster and cleaner. When there is millions of codes, this comes reasonable to do. Unless you want to hide something in/out of master code.

Reason is, there is only one starting/end point. Empty points (when ever they are empty) are only "help" points. I'm not going to go too deep to that.
But in the end...

Combinatorics in math or even in Python, gives your starting/end points and numbers of events in how many(n), where(A,B,C...) and some times when and even timers/triggers(there is many options)

Learning Hanoi Tower is useful and powerful, to understand, so when your make your code, your can use these given options and print them, with simple math code instead, of doing complex codes with errors. If you like, you can ad there as many tiny hanoi codes as you like and still, you can get right answer(just separate them with r or n option to row or new line).

I hope this was better answer now, after explanation of combinatorics.

Comment: An explanation of why this method works better would make this answer more useful for future viewers

Comment: Sorry 'bout that smac89.. I'll give that too.